# Getting runtime Error for python (Google Code Jam)

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I have tried to run my python3 code in google code jam tests however it always gives me a runtime error when testing. I would like it to not give me a runtime error. I have tested on my ubuntu python3.5.3 and it works. I am not sure what causes the runtime error, Is there a way I could get the logs from google code jam or similar?

Here is the code.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    testcases = input()
    raw = []
    while True:
        inp = input()
        if inp == "":
            break
        raw.append(inp)

    print(raw)
```

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I am new to code jam and submitting my work online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the same as what you are trying to do as far as i know. try and lemme know.
If i know what you are trying to take as inputs, i would have been able to give a more specific answer :)

```py
testcases = int(input())
for t in range(testcases):
     raw = []
     n = int(input())
     for i in range(n):
          inp = input()
          raw.append(inp)
     print(raw)
```